# Python does not start for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

```
old = [[0 for x in range(3)] for y in range(10)]
count =0
# check if the number has non-repeating digits
def different(number):
    digit_list = [0] * 4
    i = 0
    while i:
        digit_list[i] = number%10
        number /= 10
        i += 1

    for x in range(0,3):
        for y in range(x+1,3):
            if digit_list[x] == digit_list[y]:
                return False
    return True
# save the tried numbers, plus and minus values
# for prediction of the next number
def save(number,plus,minus):
    global count
    old[count][0] = number
    old[count][1] = plus
    old[count][2] = minus
    count += 1
    return
# compare for plus values
def get_plus(number1,number2):
    ret_value = 0
    for x in range(0, 3):
        if number1 % 10 == number2 % 10:
            ret_value += 1
        number1 /= 10
        number2 /= 10
    return ret_value
# compare for minus values
def get_minus(number1,number2):
    temp = [[0]*4 for i in range(2)]
    ret_value = 0
    for x in range(0,3):
        temp[0][x] = number1 % 10
        temp[0][x] = number2 % 10
        number1 /= 10
        number2 /= 10
    for x in range(0,3):
        for y in range(0,3):
            if x != y:
                if temp[0][x] == temp[1][y]:
                    ret_value += 1
    return ret_value
# compare the number to be asked with the numbers in the array
def control(number):
    for x in range(0,count-1):
        if get_plus(old[x][0],number) != old[x][1]:
            return False
        if get_minus(old[x][0],number) != old[x][2]:
            return False
    return True

def main():
    flag = False
    print('1023 ??')
    plus = input('plus ?')
    minus = input('minus ?')
    save(1023, plus, minus)
    print('4567 ??')
    plus = input('plus ?')
    minus = input('minus ?')
    save(4567, plus, minus)

    for i in range(1024, 9876):
        if different(i):
            if control(i):
                print(i + ' ??')
                plus = input('plus ?')
                minus = input('minus ?')
                save(i, plus, minus)
                if plus == 4 and minus == 0:
                    print('I WON !!!')
                    flag = True
                    break
    if not flag:
        print('False')
    return
main()
```

I am trying to make an AI for mindgame in python. But in this function it doesn't even start the for loop. Can anyone know why ?

Comment: Maybe the condition `different(i)` is never being met? Try putting an else clause in the for loop and printing something to see if the for loop is even being reached.

Comment: Are you sure `different()` returns True? What about `control()`?

Comment: I think you're going to need to be a little more specific -- So it doesn't start the loop -- What does it do?  Does it ask you for the inputs?  Does it throw an Exception at some point (if yes, what's the traceback?).  Does it hang forever for one reason or another?

Comment: Put `print i` before the `if different(i)` line to see if it enters the loop.

Comment: Best thing I think is to put prints in crucial points to see what is happening with what and where

Comment: `different` has at least one problem. The `while i:` loop will never run, because you initialize `i` to `0`, and `0` is falsey.

Comment: `old = [[0 for x in range(3)] for y in range(10)]` can be more simply written as  `old = [[0] * 3] * 10`

Answer (score 0):

The while loop in your different() function does nothing as while(0) will prevent the loop from running. Even if that would run, your different() function will always return false. At least in the last loop it will compare digit_list[3] == digit_list[3] as both loop range until 3. This is always true and the function will return false. Thus the code within your main loop will never be entered.

```
def different(number):
    digit_list = [0] * 4
    i = 0
    while i:
        digit_list[i] = number%10
        number /= 10
        i += 1

    for x in range(0,3):
        for y in range(x+1,3):
            if digit_list[x] == digit_list[y]:
                return False
    return True
```

Try this one:

```
import random

def different(num):
    digits = []
    while num >= 1:
        cur = num%10
        if cur in digits:
            return False
        digits.append(cur)
        num = (num - cur) / 10
    return True

for i in range(0, 10000):
    rand = random.randrange(1000, 10000)

    if not different(rand):
        print(rand)
```

Comment: The `while` loop never does anything.

Comment: Wow, missed that.

Comment: Your `while` loop won't check the leftmost digit, since `num` will be < 9 when you get to that iteration.